# How to implement AutoCompleteTextView using Search Dialog

Tags: android

I want to populate my quick search box using a web service. I have a web service in place which pulls the search data from a web server to put into a string array. I want the show that list of data as the user types into the search dialog. I believe the default search dialog is a simple `EditText`. How do I make it an`AutoCompleteTextView to and populate that with the string array containing my data?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to parse the data from the webservice, then store the Values/data in a String
Example: `CricketTeams`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, CricketTeams);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     } }
```

where Cricket teams will be having the data from your web service.

More detailed Example [Here](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/auto-complete-text-view-android.html)

Comment: I know how to use an `AutoCompleteTextView`. What I don't know is how to make that `AutoCompleteTextView` as my default search dialog

Comment: Get the Text from the AutoComplete TextView using `CricketTeams.getText().toString();` , and start Searching

Comment: Oh but that will not look like a search dialog right? Neither will that appear when you click on search button.